# Can you help my out with my password maker in python

Tags: python

I was trying to make a password maker that makes a random password basing on the number of specific characters you want but when i run the code it all prints the string in numbers please help me out
my code

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
print('Welcome to PyPassword Generator')
let = int(input('How many letters do you like in password?\n'))
symb = int(input('How many symbols would you like?\n'))
num =int(input('How many numbers would you like?\n'))
password =[]
l = random.choices(letters,k=let)
password.append(''.join(l))
s = random.choices(symbols,k=symb)
password.append(''.join(s))
n = random.choices(numbers,k=num)
password.append(''.join(n))
print(password)
for character in password:
    character+=character
print(f'Your password is {character}')
```

my output:

```
Welcome to PyPassword Generator
How many letters do you like in password?
2
How many symbols would you like?
3
How many numbers would you like?
4
['Wd', '+#*', '8191']
Your password is 81918191
```

Comment: You should make password a string `password = ''` then add parts like `password += ''.join(l)`

Comment: What do you think `character+=character` does…?

Answer (score 0):

```
for character in password:
    character+=character
```

goes through your password bits and just adds them onto themselves, which is not what you want.
Because all your want is to join up the bits - do this:

```
print(''.join(password))
```

Answer (score 0):

*You are using `character` to iterate over `password` list and also as a result.*

Replace this code

```
for character in password:
    character+=character
```

with this

```
character = ''
for char in password:
    character += char
```

You could also use `join()` since you just want to concatenate all the contents of password list

```
character = ''.join(password)
```